# Is anything known about the equivariant homotopy theory of surfaces with the action of a finite subgroup of the mapping class group?

Tags: mapping-class-groups, equivariant-cohomology, equivariant-homotopy

The Nielson realization theorem for a surface says that every finite subgroup of the mapping class group is realized by a finite subgroup of homeomorphisms on the surface. Furthermore, for a genus $g \geq 2$ surface, any finite subgroup has order at most $84(g-1)$ and any cyclic group has order at most $4g+2$ (according to Chapter 7 in the book of Farb and Margalit).

Once one has a finite group acting on a space, we can ask about its equivariant homotopy type. Specifically, is anything known about the Bredon (co)homology, equivariant K-theory or MU-theory, or Borel-complete (co)homology in this situation?